# How does composer require resolve dependent packages already in the project?

Tags: composer-php

When using `composer require` to add a new package to an existing project, how does composer reconcile versions of a package that is a dependency of both the existing project and of the newly required package?

Say I have a project consisting of package A and that package A depends on package B, with a version constraint of ~1.0. At the time of install, the current version of package B is 1.1, so that's what gets installed and written to the lock file.

Then a bit later I want to add package C to my project. Package C also depends on package B, but with a version constraint of >=1.0. At the time of adding package C, package B's latest release is 1.2.

When I do a `composer require C/C`, what will happen to package B? Will B remain at 1.1 as per the original installation and the lock file? Or will B be updated to the latest version (1.2)?

Consider the above again, but with the only difference that package C requires package B with a version constrain of >1.1.3. What will be the behaviour this time? Will composer refuse to install the new package C as the version constraint on the dependency B will conflict with the lock file? Or will composer update package B to the latest version (1.2)?

Comment: Why not simply try it out and see what happens? Are you facing any real problem, or is this a theoretical question about the dependency solver?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'd like to try it, but I can't see any packages which would satisfy my A,B,C simple example and I don't know how to set up my own repository to test the ideas. Its a theoretical problem at the moment whilst I write up some notes to myself, but the worry behind it is real. Could adding a package at a later date update existing dependencies in a way I'm not expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now managed to test both of the scenarios I've described above and composers behaviour is actually rather nice.

If you add a package to an existing project (with an existing lock file) using `composer require <vendor>/<package>` composer maintains the locked versions of any dependencies listed in the lock file even if newer version have been released. So in my example above, package B stays at version 1.1 as that is what is defined in the lock file.

If, when you require a new package, that package has a dependency constraint which cannot be satisfied by the currently installed versions of that dependency, **even**, if a newer version of that dependency would be compatible with the original composer.json, then composer gives the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
Can only install one of: vendor/b[v1.2, v1.1].
vendor/c v1.1 requires vendor/b ~1.2 -> satisfiable by vendor/b[v1.2].
Installation request for vendor/c ^1.1 -> satisfiable by vendor/c[v1.1].
Installation request for vendor/b (locked at v1.1, required as ~1.0) -> satisfiable by vendor/b[v1.1].
```

Where I think the key bit is `locked at v1.1`.

Doing a `composer require` does seem to implicitly do an `composer update` as @Adam suggested, but this update seems to be constrained by the existing composer.lock file. There is a difference between doing just a `composer require <vendor>/<package>` and a `composer require <vendor>/<package> --no-update` followed by a `composer update`. In the case of a `require --no-update` followed by an `update`, the behaviour differs, with all packages being resolved from scratch (no reference of the lock file), and the latest versions of the packages installed.

All of the above was tested against composer 1.10. As the results seems sensible and thought out, I've no reason to think it would have changed for 2.x, but I've not tested that.

Comment: `composer require` does **not** perform `composer update`, it only requires the new package and does **not** change existing versions

Answer (score -2):

For your first scenario, Package B at 1.2 is installed.

**Why?**
Let’s look at package C first. With a version constraint for package B of `>=1.0`, anything above that will match. Really, anything; `1.5.3`: matches. `503.8.26`: matches. Therefore, package C isn’t really required to determine what we can install, so let’s move on to package A.

For package A, the version constraint is `~1.0` which means “up to the next significant version”. For constraints with just the major.minor portion of a version, the next significant version will be a breaking change (according to semver). So for `~1.0`, all versions are available up to 2.0. Since 1.2 is within this range, it can be installed.

By default, the `require` command not only adds a dependency, but it runs the update command implicitly. You can pass the `—no-update` flag if you want to change this behavior (that’s “dash dash”, my phone likes to replace it with one character). The full list of options for `require` is here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require

For your second scenario, it will still be installed because 1.2 still meets A’s `~1.0` and C’s `>1.1.3`. The dependencies in the lock file don’t come into play for an `update` or an update as part of a `require` because the point of the update is to recreate the lock file (and installed dependencies).

Here’s an example that would cause an update to fail.
Package A requires B with `~1.0`
Package C requires package B with `>=1.2`
Package D requires package E (that requires package B with `~0.4`.

Package E’s constraint `~0.4` suggests it will only accept versions up to (but not including) 1.0, so it’s easy to think this is the reason it doesn’t work, but it’s not quite correct. The “next significant version” constraint has a special provision for packages with versions < 1.0. If a constraint has `~0.x`, the next significant version is actually 0.(x+1), not 1.0.

Package E doesn’t have to exist here, it would still fail if D had that constraint,  but this illustrates the possible complexity of dependency resolution.

You can read all the details about the ~ constraint here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#next-significant-release-operators

Comment: I really appreciate your input, but I've just worked through the scenario I described and the information is incorrect.

Comment: Which scenario, and what did you experience?

Comment: I've described my findings in my answer above.

Comment: Thanks for adding that. It’s very possible there’s a difference with composer versions 1 and 2. In the past, they’ve even changed the default activity without a breaking version change (according to semver). A few years ago if you ran a `composer install` it wouldn’t install dev dependencies unless you passed the `—dev` flag, but the made it the opposite in another 1.x release (installs dev by default but can pass a —no-dev flag). So it’s possible in your version of composer it will update only if you give it a flag, but in the latest version, it does it by default.